# laravel JWTAuth::attempt is crash on heroku

Tags: angular, laravel, heroku

I trying to deploy my app on heroku. I use laravel+angular.

everything is look ok on homepage and login page. But when I try to login, line `JWTAuth::attempt($credential)` make 500 internal server error.

I know that line caused it due to I try return response each line.

this is my login function

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->json()->all();
        $token = null;
        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $th) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }
        $user = auth()->user();
        // \Log::info(['token' => $token, 'user' => $user->id, 'name' => $user->name]);
        $role = $user->role_id;
        // event(new loginEvent('api', $user, false));
        return response()->json(compact('token', 'role'));
    }
```

and i use mysql db from [db4free.net](https://db4free.net)

What did I wrong?

Comment: Can you give us last few lines of your laravel.log?

Comment: how do i open laravel.log in heroku?